# Why am I getting this TypeError when I try to slice my Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, typeerror, slice

I pulled some stock data from a financial API and created a DataFrame with it. Columns were 'date', 'data1', 'data2', 'data3'.  Then, I converted that DataFrame into a CSV with 'date' column as index:

```
df.to_csv('data.csv', index_label='date')
```

In a second script, I read that CSV and attempted to slice the resulting DataFrame between two dates:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', parse_dates=['date'] ,index_col='date')
df = df['2020-03-28':'2020-04-28']
```

When I attempt to do this, I get the following TypeError:

```
TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.numeric.Int64Index'> with these indexers [2020-03-28] of <class 'str'>
```

So clearly, the problem is that I'm trying to use a str to slice a datetime object.  But here's the confusing part!  If in the first step, I save the DataFrame to a csv and DO NOT set 'date' as index:

```
df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

In my second script, I no longer get the TypeError:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', parse_dates=['date'] ,index_col='date')
df = df['2020-03-28':'2020-04-28']
```

Now it works just fine.  The only problem is I have the default Pandas index column to deal with.

Why do I get a TypeError when I set the 'date' column as index in my CSV...but I do NOT get a TypeError when I don't set any index in the CSV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that in your "first" instance of *df*, *date* column was an
**ordinary** column (not the index) and this DataFrame had a default
index - consecutive integers (its name is not important).

In this situation running `df.to_csv('data.csv', index_label='date')`
causes that the output file contains:

```
date,date,data1,data2,data3
0,2020-03-27,10.5,12.3,13.2
1,2020-03-28,10.6,12.9,14.7
```

i.e.:

- the **index** column (integers) was given *date* name, passed by you in
  *index_label* parameter,
- the next column, which in *df* was named *date* was **also**
  given *date* name.

Then if you read it running
`df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', parse_dates=['date'], index_col='date')`, then:

- the first *date* column (integers) has been read as *date* and
  set as the index,
- the second *date* column (dates) has been read as *date.1* and
  it is an **ordinary** column.

Now when you run `df['2020-03-28':'2020-04-28']`, you attempt to find rows
with **index** in the range given. But the index column is of *Int64Index*
type (check this in your installation), hence just the mentioned exception
was thrown.

Things look other way when you run `df.to_csv('data.csv')`.
Now this file contains:

```
,date,data1,data2,data3
0,2020-03-27,10.5,12.3,13.2
1,2020-03-28,10.6,12.9,14.7
```

i.e.:

- the first column (which in *df* was the index) has no name and *int*
  values,
- the **only** column named *date* is the second column and contains
  dates.

Now when you read it, the result is:

- *date* (converted do *DatetimeIndex*) is the **index**,
- the original index column got name *Unnamed: 0*, no surprise,
  since in the source file it had no name.

And now, when you run `df['2020-03-28':'2020-04-28']` everything is OK.

The thing to learn for the future:
Running `df.to_csv('data.csv', index_label='date')` does not set this
column as the index. It **only** saves the **current** index column
under the given name, **without any check** whether any other column has
just the same name.

The result is that 2 columns can have the same name.

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed explanation.  The solution, then, is simply to set date as the index before I create the csv in the first script.  When I do this, it works just fine.